# How can I play a notification wav file in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, audio

I want play a success/failure sound depending upon the result of a user's action. The problem I'm having is that a visible Windows Media Player dialog is being launched to play the sound. Any solutions for playing the sound without launching the dialog? I need to be able to run in IE8 and above.

Current code:

HTML

```
<a id="goodSoundId" style="display: none">good</a>
<a id="badSoundId" style="display: none">bad</a>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready( function()
{
  $('#goodSoundId' ).attr('href',"sound/alert/" + page.goodSound + ".WAV");
  $('#badSoundId' ).attr('href',"sound/alert/" + page.badSound + ".WAV");
}

var object =
{
  playGoodSound: function()
  {
     $('a#goodSoundId')[0].click();
  },
  playBadSound: function()
  {
     $('a#badSoundId')[0].click();
  }
}
```

Comment: There's the good ol' embed tag: `<embed src="goodSound.wav" hidden="true" loop="1">`

Comment: Oh check out [this doc](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put a JavaScript play inside a function and call it when required, like this:

```
function PlayDing(){
    var audio1 = new Audio('correct.mp3');
    audio1.play();
}

function PlayCross(){
    var audio2 = new Audio('incorrect.mp3');
    audio2.play();
}
```